# serializing file type field and post form data using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

i have 2 input fields and one field to upload file .i am trying to post the form using AJAX ,serializing the form data.but the problem is i am getting $_FILES empty.

here's my code:

```
           form name="dataform" id="dataform" enctype="multipart/form-data" 

              <input name="url" class="inputForm" id="url"  />

           <input type="file"  id="image" name="image" class="inputForm" />
```

```
            $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

    url: "test.php",

    data: datastring,

            success: function(resultdata){


            }

             });
```

?>

Comment: If you want to upload a file using AJAX you have to create an object Form Data and append the file to it, then pass this object as data to php: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3Le4/2/). Then you can access `$_FILES` and get the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jQuery will convert the files arrays into strings and the server can't pick it up.

But don't Worry there is always an alternate solution,

you can refer this plugin to upload images using ajax,

http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php

Its pretty simple ,you just have to submit the form using ajax and then in the php file do your upload operations and then come back to the ajax function without redirecting t aonother page.

Answer (score 0):

According to what i know you con't upload files (anything) by using ajax (with out support, you can use plugins , iframes etc)

i am from java background i don't no about PHP but i am dam sure you can achieve this by using iframes ,

see [see this link](http://wcetdesigns.com/tutorials/2012/04/08/upload-file-ajax.html)

or

i will give example how you can do (i did in my project same thing i am pasting)

```
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/catalogue/importReportaccon.action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" id="report_result" >

        <input name="fileData" type="file" id="uploadAccessionNo" class="hidden_import"/>
        <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>                 

        <a type="button" class="right button left" onclick="displayFileBrowseButton();" id="datasheet_import" title="Import" style="margin-left: -10px;">Import <span class="icon icon7"></a>

    </form>
```

Scripts

```
function displayFileBrowseButton(){
       $("#uploadAccessionNo").click();
    }


$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("uploadAccessionNo").onchange = function() {

        document.getElementById("report_result").submit();

    }

});
```

If you not understand this let me know by your comments